# cannot execute binary file (Xvfb) on mac os

Tags: node.js, macos, serverless-framework, xvfb

I am using mac os and for some reasons I have to use Xvfb but I am getting the following error:-

```
 bash: /tmp/pck/Xvfb: cannot execute binary file
```

Comment: Run `file /tmp/pck/Xvfb` and `ls -l /tmp/pck/Xvfb` to see what you've got.

Comment: i am getting this after running the file bash: /tmp/pck/Xvfb: cannot execute binary file

Comment: Is the file there?  What are it's permissions?

Comment: yep file is there and I have gave all the permissions but no luck

Comment: @stdunbar see file permission -rwxrwxrwx   1 mayank  wheel   1880832 13 Mar  2017 Xvfb

Comment: But if you just run the command `file /tmp/pck/Xvfb` what does it output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162632/discussion-between-mayank-and-stdunbar).